# How to retrieve programming language of current file in Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to develop an Eclipse plugin that guesses some properties regarding the file that is currently edited.

E.g. I'd like to guess programming language (e.g. Java, C++, xml, etc.), JRE version supported (e.g. for Java projects), etc.

I found something using the following:

```
ResourcePlugin.GetWorkspace().getRoot().getFileExtension();
ResourcePlugin.GetWorkspace().getNatureDescriptors();
ResourcePlugin.GetWorkspace().getRoot().getPersistentProperties();
```

but these are not enough for me.
Any hint about this?

Comment: getFileExtension() is your best bet. Map extensions to langauges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `IFile.getContentDescription().getContentType().getName()`... It will give you the basis for how Eclipse choose the editor used to open the file...

Comment: Ok, very good! Is there anything similar to discover OS and target platform? And, depending on the programming language, other related properties? e.g. for Java projects: running JDK and eventual minimum JDK required?

Comment: `Platform` includes a number of methods for the first question. Use `IJavaProject` and friends for the last question...